# Custom Listview/Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to implement custom listview in android that has row from smaller to bigger text as below.[image]

If not listview/recyclerview then what other component of android can i use?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean something that the selected one is the biggest font ? or it will be always from smaller to bigger to smaller ?

Comment: I think what he actually wants is having a List with items and while you swipe the one who comes on middle is selected... Something like [this](https://youtu.be/7AXFDn5qKo4) which is a circular `ListView`

Comment: Just use position as multiplier and set text size. Or you can use a integer array of text sizes.

Comment: @YamenNassif yes it will be always from smaller to bigger to smaller

Comment: @Mehdi look at the link I posted

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan yes its circular, I need that in vertical.

Comment: @Mehdi if you need something like that circular but vertical its different from what you described. In this one the listview rows font sizes / heights are changing on scrolling over the list view. while the answer i provided is fixed heights over the listview items will not change upon scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

For listview you will need something like this, after populating your list:

```
private void changeSizes() {
    View v;
    View v1;
    TextView tv; // this one depends on your layout
    TextView tv1;
    int count = myList.getCount();
    int middleRowIndex = (int)count/2 ;
    TextView midRow = myList.getAdapter().getView(middleRowIndex, null, null).findViewById(R.id.textView);
    midRow.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,(int)(count * middleRowIndex));
    int prevIndex = middleRowIndex - 1;
    int nextIndex = middleRowIndex + 1;
    while(prevIndex >=0 && nextIndex < count){
        v = myList.getAdapter().getView(prevIndex, null, null);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,(int)(count * prevIndex));
        v1 = myList.getAdapter().getView(nextIndex, null, null);
        tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,(int)(count * prevIndex));
        prevIndex--;
        nextIndex++;
    }
}
```

v,v1,tv and tv1 are views inside your custom listview so you might need to change them, also the way of calculating font sizes and setting it you might want to change it.

P.S i didn't try this code on an app, but it should work let me know in case you encountered some error.